# Dynamics elements in javascript load 2 times

Tags: javascript, jquery

First, sorry for my bad english.

I dynamically load content in my page. Each content (div) may dynamically load its own content.
So each times I load a DIV, I need to reload the JS (If I don't do that, the "new" DIV cannot load its own content).

But when I try to reload the JS, it seems to be applied 2 times. So, if I load 2 div, then I try to load 1 element in my first DIV, it will load 2 times ! (because I think the JS is run 2 times)

A picture says more than a thousand words...

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJwNl.gif

And here is the JS that load elements:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var divQuestions = document.getElementById("questions");
    $("#addQCM").click(function () { // When I load a DIV
        // Here is the link to the DIV file (html)
        $.get("/resources/views/includes/quiz/qcm.html", function (data) {
            var data = $(data);
            $(divQuestions).append(data);
        });
        // Here is the script
        reload_js('/resources/views/includes/quiz/qcm.js');
    });
});

function reload_js(src) {
    $('script[src="' + src + '"]').remove();
    $('<script>').attr('src', src).appendTo('head');
}
```

Does anybody know how to solve this ?

Thanks !

----- EDIT -----

Here is the javascript loaded:

```
$('.question').on('click', '.addOption', function () {
var group = document.createElement("div");
var fakeCircle = document.createElement("i");
fakeCircle.className = "far fa-circle fake-radiocircle";
var input = document.createElement("input");
input.type = "text";
input.className = "form-control border-0 fake-radiobutton ml-1";
input.value = "Nouvelle option";
input.required = true;
input.setAttribute('onclick', 'this.select();');
var span = document.createElement("span");
span.className = "delete-option";
span.innerHTML = '<a><i class="fas fa-times"></i></a>';
$(group).append(fakeCircle);
$(group).append(input);
$(group).append(span);
$(this).parent('div').find('.newOptions').append(group);
```

});

In some cases, variables are dynamically changed so I can't import it from simple HTML file.

Comment: Removing a script element doesn't remove the parsed script, everything in it is still available and working, including the event listeners set by the script.

Comment: Ok thanks. So what can I do ?

Comment: You've to change the architecture, load the script only once when the first page loads, then with `$.get`, load only the representative content, not the entire document. When working with dynamic content, event delegation is your best friend.

Comment: Ok I checked what is it. In fact I already do "event delegation", like that:
`$('.question').on('click', '.addOption', function () {`
But It does not help me...